# Can I get a tax deduction for giving towards my grandchildren's education?

Tags: canada, education-savings, gifts, tax-deduction

I have 4 Canadian grandchildren. Can I get a charitable tax deduction if I give towards their education?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe so, no.

You can contribute to an RESP on their behalf, and they would receive the associated government grant, but you receive no direct tax benefit.